# How do I select a range of lines until I reach a line containing specific words?

Tags: notepad++, regex

How do I select a range of lines until I reach a line containing specific words?

For example, start at line 1 and select every line until you get to a line with the words:

> hello world

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Welcome to McSoftware's! (Solution)

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the Find window.
2. Click the "Regular expression" oval.
3. Tick the ". matches newline" checkbox.
4. In the "Find what:" box, enter `(?:(?!batch).)+` replacing `batch` with whatever word you want to stop at.
5. Click in your document at the line you want to start selecting at.
6. Click the "Find Next" button in the Find window.

---

#### Explanation

We use negative lookbehind and atomic grouping features of the regular expression engine, along with Notepad++'s feature of starting to search where the cursor is positioned in the document, to implement your desired behavior.

- Notepad++ automatically highlights the result of a match.
- We **don't** want to match the word `batch` (in my example).
- We **do** want to match everything that does **not** contain the word "batch" starting at the cursor.
- See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) for details on atomic grouping.
- See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for details on negative lookbehind (and other lookaround operators, which may not be available in Notepad++'s regex flavor).

Comment: Thank you!  How would you have it search for several words?  Would this work:  (?:(?!"Hello World").)+

Comment: yes, you can just put any freeform text you want in place of "batch", but don't put quotation marks unless you actually want it to match quotation marks. If you need to use regex special characters such as parentheses, backslashes, or anything else regex uses, you'll have to escape them with a backslash.